# SQLite и AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

Подскажите, у меня есть несколько активити, и в них примерно таким способом осуществуляется вставка/чтение данных из базы:

чтение :

```
  public List<Example> loadData() {
    List<Example> test = myApplication.getDb().getApplicatonsWithTest();
    myApplication.getDb().close();
    return test;
}
```

вставка:

```
 myApplication.setExample(new Example(
            myApplication.getExample().get_id(), myApplication.getExample().valu1,
           myApplication.getExample().valu2....);
    myApplication.getDb().update(myApplication.getExample());
myApplication.getDb().close();
```

и есть класс работы с базой данных, который реализует стандартные методы: 
`addRow, deleteRow, UpdateRow`...

так вот вопрос: мне необходимо вынести все операции по работе с бд в AsyncTask,
 как поступить? в каждой активити писать свой AsyncTask и его использовать? или  можно прямо в классе работы с бд реализовать его? но тогда мне как то надо отделить методы от друг друга...

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать и один AsyncTask , но почему не воспользоваться CursorLoader? он вроде как обеспечивает работу асинхронно потоку GUI

Comment: это не ответ, а больше комментарий..